# Fill hole between a mesh and a plane

Tags: modifiers

I have a mesh and a plane, see picture 1.

I would like to append my mesh by filling the red part of the picture 2:

I tried with a Shrinkwrap modifier with the following parameters by the result is not perfect (see red part of picture 3).

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks a lot,

Maxime
http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3146/

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell from a single perspective what's going on in the projection. Could you provide more information?

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)

Here are some other views: [link](http://maxsoft.be/blender.png) The red part is a not wished behaviour.

Comment: If it possible, I would suggest to upload this part of your project to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so we can have a deeper look at the interaction between the two objects.

Comment: The file is here: (There is an modifier for the mesh (sole) that is not visible)

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3146" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3146/)

Comment: The modifier is working as expected. Maybe you can try to limit the vertices taken into account with the Vertex group option: http://imgur.com/a/1lDHb. But all really depends on what your modeling needs are. What is your final goal?